# spl-token-cli: "Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit" after `solana airdrop 1`

Tags: spl-token, spl-token-cli

I'm working through the https://spl.solana.com/token docs using spl-token-cli built from source and getting an unexpected error near the very beginning.

```
~/solana-program-library:master:> cargo build; and cargo run --bin spl-token create-token

Creating token 9FEtLS7ZPcSCPNEhHWaTAxx5YHzF6nNGWUie1uPh2v3h
Error: Client(ClientError { request: Some(SendTransaction), kind: RpcError(RpcResponseError { code: -32002, message: "Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit.", data: SendTransactionPreflightFailure(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: Some(AccountNotFound), logs: Some([]), accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(0), return_data: None }) }) })
```

```
$ solana config get

~/s/t/cli> solana config get
Config File: /Users/bert/.config/solana/cli/config.yml
RPC URL: https://api.devnet.solana.com
WebSocket URL: wss://api.devnet.solana.com/ (computed)
Keypair Path: /Users/bert/.config/solana/devnet.json
Commitment: confirmed
```

```
$ solana address
FNF7gJSK2V9ghvLzddjhyyG5PxDLqr7pxdYobiS7wZG6
```

https://explorer.solana.com/address/FNF7gJSK2V9ghvLzddjhyyG5PxDLqr7pxdYobiS7wZG6?cluster=devnet

shows a balance of 7.989352282 Sol for my account.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a bug in solana-program-library/master.

git bisect points to [cc2739fce19537ae454ee513da96698d79362c53](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/commit/cc2739fce19537ae454ee513da96698d79362c53).

`cargo install spl-token-cli` installs spl-token-cli v2.0.17, which doesn't exhibit the problem:

```
~> spl-token create-token
Creating token JCevPjvSnCfW4pjvhs1s9NDFDC1mXjKZh56uNFP3Z7Qh

Address:  JCevPjvSnCfW4pjvhs1s9NDFDC1mXjKZh56uNFP3Z7Qh
Decimals:  9

Signature: 2XkTZTsiQFZG8GnqSLH844RBd2xzoRjVm6DjdWKvcFSo24a2uucngZrLrxv4bNLbhAdGJuzG5wCTWjpyHxYg6CrB
```

Answer (score 1):

just for sake of posterity, this was fixed in master and should not be an issue in any existing release